# `RwLockWriteGuard<'_, T>` does not implement the traits T implements

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I would like to deserialize JSON objects from a stream, however that stream is wrapper in a `RwLock`. So the following does not work:

```
let mut stream:RwLockWriteGuard<'_, I2pStream> = wrapped_stream.write().await; // I2pStream implements the `Read` and `Write` Traits
let iterator = serde_json::Deserializer::from_reader(stream).into_iter::<serde_json::Value>();
for item in iterator {
  // ...
}
```

...since `the trait 'std::io::Read' is not implemented for 'tokio::sync::RwLockWriteGuard<'_, I2pStream>'`. I expected the `RwLockWriteGuard` would implement all traits its content type implements, since I can also call functions like `read()`, `read_buf(...)` etc. on the write guard (which are the `Read` trait's functions).

So is there a way to let the compiler know my write guard indeed *does* implement the `std::io::Read` trait? Or is there some other solution like wrapping the write guard in something which is a reader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RwLockWriteGuard<'_, T>` derefs into a `T`, so it gets all of `T`’s methods, but it does not automatically implement the traits that `T` implements. The issue is that `serde_json::Deserializer::from_reader` needs a `Read`, but only `I2pStream`, not `RwLockWriteGuard<'_, I2pStream>`, implements `Read`.

I *think* you can solve this by simply forcing the `Deref`: `serde_json::Deserializer::from_reader(&mut *stream)`; the blanket [`impl<R: Read + ?Sized> Read for &mut R`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/io/trait.Read.html#impl-Read-for-%26mut+R) should be sufficient.

Comment: It's black magic to me why this `&mut *stream` construction works, but it does and I'm grateful for that :) Thanks!

Comment: `*stream` derefs into a `I2pStream`, which would work on its own (since `I2pStream: Read`), except you can't move out of a `RwLockWriteGuard`. The `&mut` “undoes” the deref (avoiding the “cannot move out of” error) and creates a `&mut I2pStream`, which is also `Read`.

Comment: @philhob If `&mut *x` is too magical, remember that you can always call `x.deref_mut()` explicitly. (You'll just need to `use std::ops::DerefMut` to bring `deref_mut()` into scope.) But I suggest to embrace the dark side and learn to love `&mut *x`. :)